# Selenium: Choosing from a drop-down menu

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I'm trying to automate and I'm running into a bit of a problem trying to select from a drop-down menu. I am able to start a Chrome session and log into the page, but when I get there it seems as if it's not locating the element properly.

The drop-down menu: LINKNOLONGERAVAILABLE

HTML Code for the drop down menu: LINKNOLONGERAVAILABLE

My code for the webdriver:

```
s1 = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("X")) 

s1.select_by_value("X")
```

Not sure if I'm selecting the right ID or if I need to implement something else (like waits?). I've tried xpath, css selector, by name, and by id, but to no avail.

Thanks for all your help!

Edit: The elements were wrapped in an iFrame, all I had to do was switch frame and it worked :D

Comment: What exception does it throw?

Answer (score 1):

In case you would want to try with waits , you can follow this code :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
drop_down= wait.until(EC.visibility_of((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select.PSDROPDOWNLIST[name^='TL_RPTD_TIME_PUNCH_TYPE'][id^='TL_RPTD_TIME_PUNCH_TYPE']")))  

select = Select(drop_down)

# select by visible text
select.select_by_visible_text('Transfer')
```

I am not sure whether ID is unique so, I have constructed a css selector with **ID,name and class name**.

You will have to imports these :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Hope that will help.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the reply. I implemented everything and it's sending me this error. For context, I included everything for you:

Here's my code: https://pastebin.com/x1pxEbaV

Here is the error: https://gyazo.com/7d9754eff15633c72cfd101b23eb1f53

Comment: The URL you have shared (https://hr92.ps.chla.usc.edu/psc/PCHL2J/EMPLOYEE/HRMS/c/NUI_FRAMEWORK.PT_AGSTARTPAGE_NUI.GBL?CONTEXTIDPARAMS=TEMPLATE_ID%3aPTPPNAVCOL&scname=ADM_TIME_ABSENCE_LINKS&PTPPB_GROUPLET_ID=UC_TIME_ABSENCE&CRefName=CHLA_NAVCOLL_1)  is saying site can't be reached. Can you just share the domain

Comment: Sorry, it can't be reached because it's on an intranet at my place of employment. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you just print : `elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("select.PSDROPDOWNLIST[name^='TL_RPTD_TIME_PUNCH_TYPE'][id^='TL_RPTD_TIME_PUNCH_TYPE']")`  then `print(len(elements)) `

Comment: Are you using is_displayed anywhere in code ? Cause the exception is for that.

Comment: I ran the above code that you suggested, and the length was printed out to be 0. No "is_displayed" anywhere in my code either.

Comment: That means it is not able to find the element. We will have to change the locator , just remove name and id parentheses from css selector and print the statements again.

Comment: Would the code look like this?
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("select.PSDROPDOWNLIST[]")

Comment: Just remove [] , rest seems to be fine.

Comment: Okay, just ran it again and the result was 0

Comment: 0 means , the locator we have written is not picking the value from DOM. Is it possible to give the access for your environment, or make your URL available at my end?

Comment: I don't think I can because you have to physically be here in the building in order to access it, through their wifi. I took a screenshot of the HTML to make sure we're not missing anything: https://gyazo.com/f4b4bde48e0093ce973afb1ae90e270d

Comment: This problem is very simple. The css selector has to be changed, rest all looks fine.